# Templated virtual member functions are forbidden, are there alternatives?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, virtual-functions

Let's say I have something like this:

```
class Outer
{
public:
    void send(A a) { ... }
    template <typename MessageType>
    void send(MessageType message) { innerBase->doSend(message); }
private:
    InnerBase* innerBase;
};
```

where `InnerBase` being a polymorphic base class:

```
class InnerBase
{
public:
    virtual void doSend(B b) = 0;
    virtual void doSend(C c) = 0;
    virtual void doSend(D d) = 0;
};

class InnerDerived : public InnerBase
{
public:
    virtual void doSend(B b) override { ... }
    virtual void doSend(C c) override { ... }
    virtual void doSend(D d) override { ... }
};
```

So far so good, and if I want to add overloads I just need to add them to `InnerBase` and `InnerDerived`.

At some point, it turns out I need to make the outer class customizable too, so I'd like to be able to write something like this :

```
class OuterBase
{
public:
    template <typename MessageType>
    virtual void send(MessageType message) = 0;
};

class OuterDerived : public OuterBase
{
public:
    void send(A a) { ... }
    template <typename MessageType>
    virtual void send(MessageType message) override { innerBase->send(message); }
private:
    InnerBase* innerBase;
};
```

But that's not allowed by the standard, which forbids templated virtual member functions. Instead I'm forced to write all the overloads one by one like this :

```
class OuterBase
{
public:
    virtual void send(A a) = 0;
    virtual void send(B b) = 0;
    virtual void send(C c) = 0;
    virtual void send(D d) = 0;
};

class OuterDerived : public OuterBase
{
public:
    virtual void send(A a) override { ... }
    virtual void send(B b) override { innerBase->doSend(b); }
    virtual void send(C c) override { innerBase->doSend(c); }
    virtual void send(D d) override { innerBase->doSend(d); }
private:
    InnerBase* innerBase;
};
```

That's a lot of boilerplate code, and that means that if I ever want to add another overload I need to modify 4 classes instead of just 2 (and twice as many files). Assuming I need more than one level of indirection, this could easily go up to 6, 8, etc, making the addition of new overloads totally impractical.

Am I doing this wrong? Is there a cleaner way to do this?

The only alternative I can think of would be to leak the `innerBase` pointer to the base class so that it can call `doSend()` directly, which would allow to keep `send()` templated, but that both breaks encapsulation and prevents `OuterDerived` from adding its own `send()` overloads
as well as from adding its own logic around the calls to `doSend()`...

Comment: Sounds like something that is normally solved with the [*visitor pattern*](https://refactoring.guru/design-patterns/visitor).

Comment: You could also fully template this, take a look at the packet structure of [boost beast](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_70_0/libs/beast/doc/html/beast/using_http/message_containers.html). Perhaps you could use something similar and fully templatize your messages so you don't need `A`, `B`, etc.

Comment: @FantasticMrFox What would that look like, here? Making all my messages inherit from a base type Message, passing a Message* from the outerbase to the innerbase, and then calling message->send(innerBase), which would be polymorphic and call the correct overload with innerBase->send(this)? it kind of feels like there's a risk I'd need to overload message::send() at some point, want to template it, and find myself with the same issue...

Comment: "it kind of feels like there's a risk" [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it). You solve a problem when you *have* a problem. Say you have two outer classes `Green` and `Blue`, and two message classes `Soft` and `Hard`, do you really need *four* unrelated `sendMessage` implementations, not reducible to some kind of 2x2 matrix?

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm. Well, for a start, I can't call message->send(outerDerived) without overloading, i.e, I can't handle the send(A) case from my example. In my actual problem, the outer classes are totally independent communication protocols, which should support sending various kinds of data, and one of the protocols has to negotiate which version of one of its subsections to use (the inner classes). If i wrap the data I send into classes inheriting from Message, it doesn't make sense to make Message depend on the subsection's interface.

Answer (score 1):

> That's a lot of boilerplate code, and that means that if I ever want to add another overload I need to modify 4 classes instead of just 2 (and twice as many files).

While multiple levels of inheritance kind of smells bad, the naive solution might be the best here: add one derived class that forwards to `InnerBase` and derive from that:

```cpp
class OuterInnerProxy : public OuterBase
{
public:
    OuterInnerProxy(InnerBase* innerBase) : innerBase(innerBase) {}
    virtual void send(B b) override { innerBase->doSend(b); }
    virtual void send(C c) override { innerBase->doSend(c); }
    virtual void send(D d) override { innerBase->doSend(d); }
private:
    InnerBase* innerBase;
};

class OuterDerived : public OuterInnerProxy
{
public:
    OuterDerived(InnerBase* innerBase) : innerBase(innerBase) {}
    virtual void send(A a) override { /* ... */ }
}
```

Now you're only modifying 3 classes. But let's say you wanted to avoid typing all those overloads *at all*. Then you can get all overengineery with variadic templates. Our goal will be to make this work:

```cpp
using OuterBaseT = OuterBase<A, B, C, D>;
using OuterInnerProxyT = OuterInnerProxy<OuterBaseT>; // overrides B, C, D
struct OuterDerived : OuterInnerProxyT {
    OuterDerived(InnerBase* innerBase);
    virtual void send(A a) override { /* ... */ }
};
```

First, the variadic outer base is pretty easy if you're using C++17. If you're not, then you can still do this in C++11 with recursive inheritance, which is less pretty and slower to compile:

```cpp
template <typename T>
class OuterBaseSingle
{
public:
    virtual void send(T t) = 0;
};

template <typename... Ts>
class OuterBase : OuterBaseSingle<Ts>...
{
public:
    using OuterBaseSingle<Ts>::send...;
};
```

The first part of making `OuterInnerProxyT` is to determine which `Ts`  in `OuterBase<Ts...>` have overloads in `InnerBase`. A simple way to do that is to use SFINAE to convert each type into a full or empty tuple, then mash them together with `std::tuple_cat`:

```cpp
template <typename T, typename = void>
struct InnerBaseOverload {
    using Type = std::tuple<>;
};
template <typename T>
struct InnerBaseOverload<T, decltype(std::declval<InnerBase>().doSend(std::declval<T>()))> {
    using Type = std::tuple<T>;
 };
template <typename T>
struct InnerBaseOverloads;
template <typename...Ts>
struct InnerBaseOverloads<OuterBase<Ts...>> {
    using Type = decltype(std::tuple_cat(std::declval<typename InnerBaseOverload<Ts>::Type>()...));
};
```

Next, define classes that override `send` for a single type. We can use virtual inheritance to make sure they have a common `OuterBase` and `InnerBase*`. MSVC yells at me if I don't explicitly invoke the virtual base at every level, but it won't get called:

```cpp
class OuterInnerProxyBase {
public:
    OuterInnerProxyBase(InnerBase* innerBase) : innerBase(innerBase) { }
    InnerBase* innerBase;
};

template <typename T, typename... Ts>
class OuterInnerProxySingle : public virtual OuterInnerProxyBase, public virtual OuterBase<Ts...> {
public:
    using OuterBase<Ts...>::send;
    OuterInnerProxySingle() : OuterInnerProxyBase(nullptr) { }
    void send(T t) override { OuterInnerProxyBase::innerBase->doSend(t); }
};
```

Finally, we can combine them using a little partial specialization:

```cpp
template <typename TOuterBase, typename TOverloadTuple>
class OuterInnerProxyImpl;

template <typename... TOuterArgs, typename... TOverloads>
class OuterInnerProxyImpl<OuterBase<TOuterArgs...>, std::tuple<TOverloads...>> : public OuterInnerProxySingle<TOverloads, TOuterArgs...>... { };

template <typename T>
using OuterInnerProxy = OuterInnerProxyImpl<T, typename InnerBaseOverloads<T>::Type>;
```

Add some extra boilerplate to initialize the virtual base and lift the `send` overloads, And that's it:

```cpp
using OuterBaseT = OuterBase<A, B, C, D>;
class OuterDerived : public OuterInnerProxy<OuterBaseT> {
public:
    OuterDerived(InnerBase* inner) : OuterInnerProxyBase(inner) { }
    using OuterBaseT::send; 
    virtual void send(A a) override { /* ... */ }
};
```

Demo:
https://godbolt.org/z/7z7Exo

One caveat though: This runs happily on msvc 2019, clang 11, and gcc 10.1. But for whatever reason, it segfaults on gcc 10.2 on godbolt. I'm trying to build gcc 10.2 it on my PC to figure out why, if it's not a compiler bug. Will update when I debug it.

Comment: So, if I follow, you're using variadic templates to so that `OuterBase<T...>` supports `send()` for each type listed in the template thanks to multiple layers of inheritance, and then you use OuterInnerProxy<T...> to implement all the `send()` overloads one by one through multiple layers of inheritance too? And then, at the end, in OuterDerived, since you inherit from it you can override one of the overloads. Is that the idea? That does seem like it'd work, but I'm not sure what the impact of all those layers inheritances would be. Also if it's hard to understand, my coworkers will hate me...

Comment: Runtime overhead will be negligible - structs all get flattened into bytes and offsets in the end, and you're already using virtual methods. Compile times will go up with all the template shenanigans. Your last point is very valid - "tricky" code isn't much good if no one can read it, and boilerplate can be less harmful than the alternative. You can also go in between - for instance if you take out the code that deduces which types have a `doSend` overload it's a little more boilerplate and a little less complex.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a fixed number of overloads on `send`, then I'd suggest add each overload to the vtable as your already doing. Then for each implementation, you just forward each vtable definition to a template definition defined in each derived class.

If you want an unlimited number of overloads, unfortunately your out of luck here. To do this safely, this requires a language feature called higher rank or rank-n types and higher rank types require some level of type erasure like Java's generics. So instead you have to do manual type erasure, where you pass in a pointer and a dictionary, and be careful to not mix up your types.

For example, consider this pseudo C++:

```
// stuff you can do with A
erasure template <pointer A>
struct Dictonary {
    std::function<A()> create;
    std::function<A(A)> increment;
};

class OuterBase
{
public:
     erasure template <pointer A> virtual void send(A a, Dirtonary<A>) = 0;
};
```

and after manual type erasure:

```
// stuff you can do with A
struct Dictonary {
    std::function<void*()> create;
    std::function<void*(void*)> increment;
};

class OuterBase
{
public:
     virtual void send(void* a, Dirtonary) = 0;
};
```

Also, if all your the functions you need to use for A involve `this` you can define a new base class rather then rely on dictionary passing.

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually need to duplicate code in `OuterDerived`, it is enough to have all `Message` classes to derive from a common base.

```
class InnerBase
{
public:
    virtual void doSend(Message* m) = 0;
};

class OuterBase : public InerBase
{
public:
    void doSend(MessageBase* m) override {
        m->sendme(innerBase);
    }
private:
    InnerBase* innerBase;
};
```

This is a standard double dispatch technique. `sendme` needs to be virtual.

```
class MessageBase {
public:
   virtual void sendme(InnerBase* innerBase) = 0;
};

class MessageA : public MessageBase {
public:
   void sendme(InnerBase* innerBase) override {
      // this chooses the correct overload
      innerBase->send(*this);
   }
};
```

Now messageA doesn't need to be an actual message, it could be a wrapper around one, and that wrapper can be a template:

```
template <class Message>
class MessageWrapper : public MessageBase
{
public:
   void sendme(InnerBase* innerBase) override {
      // this chooses the correct overload
      innerBase->send(message);
   }
 private:
   Message message;
};
```

Now `doSend` is independent of the actual message type, messages know nothing about either inner or outer classes, outer classes know nothing about specific messages, and only innet classes (each of them) keep the knowledge about specific messages (each of them). So you still need NxM `send` functions, but in exactly one place, in the inner class hierarchy.